# One headset to rule them all?

Tags: video, audio

Looking for off the shelf or hack solution.

A headset /mic or mixer that can get my Droid, Desktop, and Cisco IP phone (7941) together.

One headset to listen to music take cell and work calls. Right now I'm wearing out my jacks and swapping out headsets.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try wiring all three outputs into the headphones...I think it should be fine as long as only one of them make sound at the same time. Basically get two of [these splitters](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10218&cs_id=1021802&p_id=669&seq=1&format=2) and possibly some [extensions](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10218&cs_id=1021808&p_id=648&seq=1&format=2) depending on how far apart your devices are. You might need some extra or different cables to handle the mic, but you should be able to get the idea of what I'm suggesting.

Another possibility: Route the sound from your phones into your PC, then just connect a headset to the PC. (Use a wire for the desk phone, and bluetooth for the cellphone)

Answer (score 0):

This may be of interest, I don't know if i can connect to the Droid, but it works with anything that has bluetooth. 
I don't own this, so i can't tell you how well it works, but i was looking at buying a set for a similar problem to yours and these seem to the best off the shelf solution, for me, at least.

http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Rocketfish%26%23153%3B+Mobile+-+RF-MAB2+High-Definition+Stereo+Bluetooth+Headphones+-+Black/9246862.p?id=1218068108153&skuId=9246862&st=rocketfish

Comment: That doesn't look like it has a microphone?

Comment: Yeah - it's only headphones, not a headset

Comment: It does have a mic in it. very small, but it does have a mic. Best buy does not show it, but on the actually package it does.

Answer (score 0):

A switchbox of some sort?  Bing found me a 2-port device on the first search http://www.headsetsdirect.com/accessories/05344-42.html so there's probably devices with more ports out there too.